# Dice game query While loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, dice

I am trying to create a dice game using a while loop and if's. I have done this successfully however I am trying to figure out how to program the game so that if numbers 4,6 or 12 are not input it will state invalid choice and will ask diceChoice again. 
Can anybody help?

So far I have...

```
rollAgain = "Yes" or "yes" or "y"

while rollAgain == "Yes" or "yes" or "y":
    diceChoice = input ("Which dice would you like to roll; 4 sided, 6, sided or 12 sided?")
    if diceChoice == "4":
        import random 
        print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,4)) 
    if diceChoice == "6":
        import random
        print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,6))
    if diceChoice == "12":
        import random
        print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,12))

    rollAgain = input ("Roll Again?") 
print ("Thank you for playing")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [if x or y or z == blah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah)

Comment: You probably want your import outside the while loop

Comment: it should still work inside, maybe not the best though.. haha

Comment: The condition on your while loop is also wrong, as it is equivalent to  `while (rollAgain == "Yes") or ("yes") or ("y"):`, and since "yes" and "y" are truthy, it will never exit. See sihrc's answer for a fix

Comment: see my answer for an explanation of `in`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed While Loop, Tidied up all the repetition. Moved import statement to the top. Structured to allow more options for rollAgain and diceChoice.

```
import random

rollAgain = "Yes"

while rollAgain in ["Yes" , "yes", "y"]:
    diceChoice = input ("Which dice would you like to roll; 4 sided, 6, sided or 12 sided?")
    if diceChoice in ["4","6","12"]:
        print("You rolled a ",random.randint(1,int(diceChoice)))
    else:
        print "Please input 4,6, or 12."
    rollAgain = input ("Roll Again?") 

print ("Thank you for playing")
```

Doing this sort of assignment:

```
rollAgain = "Yes" or "yes" or "y"
```

Is unnecessary - only the first value will be inputted. Pick one for this variable; you only need one for its purposes.

This sort of assignment doesn't work here either:

```
while rollAgain == "Yes" or "yes" or "y":
```

It will again only check the first value. You either have to split it up like other posters have done, or use a different data structure that will incorporate them all like a list in the code above.

Comment: +1 for noticing that the while condition is wrong in the asker's code. Might want to mention that explicitly though

Comment: That is great thank you. Didnt think of doing it that way I am new to Python so starting to pick up new methods. You have taught me how to do an array too I beleive thank you. what does the in function do please?

Comment: It checks if the value at rollAgain is somewhere in the list. returns a boolean

Answer (score 1):

You should only import random once at the top

```
import random  #put this as the first line
```

Your rollAgain declaration should only set it to one value

```
rollAgain = "yes"  # the or statements were not necessary
```

You forgot to do `rollAgain ==` in your subsequent conditionals, here is a simpler way

```
while rollAgain.lower().startswith("y"):  #makes sure it starts with y or Y
```

To do an **invalid input** statement, you could use `elif:` and `else:` statements to keep it simple

```
if diceChoice == "4":
    print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,4)) 
elif diceChoice == "6":
    print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,6))
elif diceChoice == "12":
    print("You rolled a ", random.randint(1,12))
else:
    print("Invalid Input, please enter either 4, 6, or 12")
```

Your old while loop would never have exit because you were basically saying this

```
while rollAgain == "Yes" or True or True  #because non-empty strings are treated as True
```

**edit** since you asked about `in` statements, here is a brief example

```
>>>5 in [1,2,3,4]
False
>>>5 in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
```

The `in` statement is similar to a `contains()` in other languages it checks to see if the variable is inside the list

Since `5` is not in the list `[1,2,3,4]` it returned `False`
however, `5` IS in the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` so it returns `True`

You could use this several places in your code, specifically if you want to make sure a variable is within a set of options.  I didn't recommend it to keep it simple for you.

Comment: That is fantastic thank you very much Stephan for clearing that up for me. I'm new to Python so the methods I have learnt so far is what I have been using to attempt to solve problems however what you have explained is of real assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
diceChoice = None
while diceChoice not in ["4","12","6"]:
    diceChoice = input("enter choice of dice(4,6,12)")
print "You picked %d"%diceChoice
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my take on it:

```
# If you are only using one function from random
# then it seems cleaner to just import that name
from random import randint
while True:
    choice = int(input("Which dice would you like to roll; 4 sided, 6, sided or 12 sided?\n:"))
    # Using sets for 'in' comparisons is faster
    if choice in {4, 6, 12}:
        print("You rolled a", randint(1, choice))
    else:
        print("Please input 4, 6, or 12.")
    # Make the input lowercase so that it will accept anything that can be
    # interpreted as "yes".
    if input("Roll Again?\n:").lower() not in {"yes", "y"}:
        # End the game by breaking the loop
        break
# You should use an input at the end to keep the window open to see the results
input("Thank you for playing!")
```